# Textview is not showing anything

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

My textview shows blank! Even when I put a String, it shows blank..Please tell me what to do

```
protected void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState ) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    result.setText("TESTING");
```

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove throwing exceptions from onCreate and then check.

Comment: i tried..still nothing

Comment: its working fine but if its problem with yours code then please put your full code here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have created one program with your code, its working fine here...

i have just removed below 4 line :

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the padding properties for the RelativeLayout. Try commenting out all the padding properties and check.

Comment: Dude how does the answer marked correct tells anything different than what this answer says?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a position attribute to the TextView, for example set it's **alignParentTop="true"**

Comment: make sure you're referencing the correct layout file activity_main

Answer (score 0):

Remove Paddings and then check. There does not seem any other factor stopping the text to display.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this its done..

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            result.setText("TESTING");

        }


       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       tools:context=".MainActivity" >

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why you used throws ClientProtocolException in class? just try with simple.

Answer (score 0):

Change text color.

In XML,

```
android:textColor="#FF0000"
```

Or else in Java

```
myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
```